# addEventListener null, onclick works (onload did not work and js is in separate document)

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I can use onClick in my HTML file to call upon functions created in my JavaScript file, however, attempting to use `addEventListener` does not work and I am not sure why. Error in `console.log` says that the `addEventListner` is null.

I am attempting to change the display of my web page via a click event.

I understand that `addEventListener` does not cancel out the previous event called, but even the first event called in my code does not trigger the change which is confusing.

After looking this up I tried the following:

- Using `window.onload = function(){}` and placing the below code within the function.

  `document.getElementById('begin_game').addEventListener('click', beginGame);`

  `document.getElementById('select_category').addEventListener('click', selectCategory);`
- Using this code independent of the `window.onload` function but the `addEventListener` still returned as null.

---

The `beginGame` and `selectCategory` functions reference the following code in the js file:

```
function Hide(x) {
  const hidden = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i=0, length= hidden.length; i < length; i++) {
    if ( hidden[i].style.display != 'none') {
      hidden[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

function Display(x) {
  const show = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i = 0, length = show.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (show[i].style.display != 'flex') {
      show[i].style.display = 'flex';
    }
  }
}

//Below is how the functions are referenced
function beginGame() {
  document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'flex';
  Hide('start');
}

function selectCategory () {
  Hide('welcome-content');
  Display('category');
}

// Where I would place the event listeners I mentioned above
// document.getElementById('begin_game').addEventListener('click', beginGame);

// document.getElementById('select_category').addEventListener('click', selectCategory);

// When I used the window.onload function, I placed it at the bottom of the js page
```

---

Buttons from HTML file

```
    <button type='submit' class='welcome-content' id='select_category'>
        Categories
    </button>

    </div>

    <h1 class= 'start'>
        Math Maniacs
    </h1>
    <button type='submit' class='start' id='begin_button'>
        START
    </button>
```

Comment: Why is there not element with id 'begin_game' ?

Comment: @NickLee
I edited it to reflect the code in my text editor. Sorry about that! Double checked my site, even with the matching id the button still doesn't work with the event listener

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better answers more quickly. Walls of irrelevant code make more work for people that could help you and don't contribute anything.

Comment: @3ocene I changed the format of the question to better comply with the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `window.onload` was the correct solution, I realized that I was not enveloping all of the relevant js code with the onload function.

Before I did this

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('begin_game').addEventListener('click', beginGame);

     document.getElementById('select_category').addEventListener('click', selectCategory);
 }
```

However, I believe that didn't work because I did not place the functions the event listeners were referencing into the window.onload function.

Once I wrote the below

```
window.onload = function() {
 function beginGame() {
    document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'flex';
    Hide('start');
}

 document.getElementById('begin_button').addEventListener('click', beginGame);

 function selectCategory() = {
    Hide('welcome-content');
    Display('category');
}

 document.getElementById('select_category').addEventListener('click', selectCategory);

}
```

The code worked as intended

Comment: That's interesting. You shouldn't need to have the function declaration within the `onload` function. Additionally, the syntax defining the `selectCategory` function is incorrect. You should not have a `=` there.

Comment: @3ocene I figured it was because the buttons were supposed to reveal an overlay so the elements that it wanted technically haven't loaded yet. Thanks for pointing out the =, I converted from an arrow function to keep the code in the same format and must have forgot it

Comment: `document.getElementById('welcome')` is only called when the function is executed, not when the function is defined. Just like how selectors within the `onload` function are called when the function is executed, not when it's defined.

Comment: Makes sense. I originally thought the function was executed when the button was clicked  which was why I was confused when my code outside of the window.onload function wasn't working.